# How to deal with external type?

Tags: java, unit-testing, architecture, domain-driven-design

Suppose I have some project which needs to communicate with third party APIs. It leaves external types to scatter everywhere in my code. Even my test cases needs to import these types.

Now suppose I have a marshaling service that converts the external type to some `DTO`; I need a test to verify the behavior of my service, for that I would need text fixtures of the external type.

```
class Marshalling {
  private Marshalling() {}

  static Api.LineItemRequest requestToProto(LineItem lineItem) {
    SomeBuilder builder = SomeClass.newBuilder()
        .setType(lineItem.getLineItemType().toString())
        .setStatus(lineItem.getStatus().toString());
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

Now, the external type is not easy to create. What should I do? should I give some dummy type to my service?

The reference to the type is [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-java-lib/blob/127e405f651e88a64553e576ab8f26e72bdde42e/modules/dfp_axis/src/main/java/com/google/api/ads/dfp/axis/v201508/LineItem.java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the external type is difficult to create, go ahead and use a mock ([EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), etc), but I would try and create the real object if possible.  Try passing nulls for everything you don't care about.  It also looks like that object has a no-argument constructor, and then a bean API, so you should be able to construct it, then just set the bits you find necessary.

Comment: but it has around 100 parameters and most of them are some other third party types.

Comment: Do you need any of those params?  It's a bean.  Use the no-argument constructor, set the values that you are interested in testing against, and leave the rest blank.

Comment: you mean if I need only order Id, then I can just do `lineItem.setOrderId()` and rest everything will be taken care of?

Comment: It is not certain, I would certainly start there.  Only if that methodology fails would I investigate using mocks like I mentioned in my post.

Comment: So, its ok to use external types in the code base? shouldn't I wrap that type with my domain type?

Comment: @vivek your Marshaller is already a wrapper around the third party API. It should live in the Infrastructure layer of your application or in some kind of [anti-corruption layer](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/07/domain-driven-design-anti-corruption-layer/) where it is OK to reference external stuff.

Comment: @guillaume31 here Marshaller is just converting the response of my service into the suitable wire format. Second, I see that `LineItem` is sprinkled over all my code base.

Comment: @RobConklin I see one quirk while instantiating `LineItem`, although its a bean but suppose if I do `item.setStatus()` then it needs some `ComputedStatus` as its parameter which is again a external type. What you are saying is first I instantiate that `ComputedStatus` then inject int that set method. This is one example, I see there are ~20 params like that.

Comment: @vivek quote from your question : "I have a marshaling service that *converts the external type to some DTO*". How does that not wrap third party types ?

Comment: @vivek @RobConklin will correct me if I'm wrong, but he was referring to creating the real object **in your test for Marshalling**, not in production code. Having `LineItem` sprinkled all over your **production** code base seems like a smell.

Comment: @guillaume31 Marshalling is just one part where I need this Type, there are places in my application too which needs that, yes its seems a code smell and it seems fairly common scenario to me. What is the solution when you need third party Type in your code?

Comment: I think @vivek was pointing out that this is normally handled by mapping the external type into a DTO.  This decouples your code from the external type, and centralizes the bindings to somewhere you can safely test.

Comment: @vivek Did you read the article I linked to ? The solution is to reformulate what a `LineItem` represents in your own Domain and create a type for it (isn't that what you did with `LineItemRequest` ?) Then create an anticorruption layer module that will talk in terms of `LineItem`s to the external API but in terms of this new domain concept to the rest of your application. This is the only place where you'll manipulate `LineItem`s.